# JQuery: $(window).resize() not working

Tags: jquery, google-chrome

I'm trying to manually fire the $(window).resize() method on page load.
I created a function to center a div element vertically and horizontally on the page

```
$(window).resize(function(){
    $('.pagecentered').css({
        position: 'absolute',
        left: ($(window).width() - $('.pagecentered').outerWidth())/2,
        top: ($(window).height() - $('.pagecentered').outerHeight())/2
    });
});
```

After this function I call

```
$(window).resize();
```

to fire the resize() event manually.

Unfortunately it doesn't work. On reload the div is not centered as expected.
If I resize the browser window the div element is centered it only isn't fired on page load.

Is there any way to solve this?
I'm using Chrome 27.0.1453.116 m (latest version atm) and JQuery 1.10.2

Comment: is code wrapped in document ready ?

Comment: ah ok that was the problem. pretty new to javascript^^ thanks r043v

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use [`trigger`](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/) : `$(window).trigger('resize');`

Comment: This is not required but matter of style. The documentation is pretty explicit - when used without parameters, `resize()` is shortcut for `.trigger('resize')`.

Comment: Why is this best answer?

Comment: Hmm that's confusing. I'm guessing the other answer might have been deleted? My previous comment doesn't even make sens to me!